# Delphi run console application from form application

Tags: delphi, console, indy10

How to run a console application from a standard Delphi form application, but to run it hidden? Also i want to write commands in that console application from my form application. 
How can i do those things?

And a personal request for the people who have the newest version of indy10. I have trouble to compile [the console application](http://www.mediafire.com/?zlblrkciri8fvzk) and if is possible some of you to compile it for me and give me link to download. Please, that will be nice if you do me that favor. :)

Comment: how do you plan to communicate with console app? Passing arguments or stdin?

Comment: @David It is very possible using a pipe ;)

Comment: @David Sorry,missunderstood your question

Comment: This question is kind of a duplicate of multiple other questions.  I think you should ask one question at a time.   I'm downvoting not because I dislike you, or any of your individual questions, but because I think this is too many questions all in one. You mention indy10, console application stdin capture, launching subprocesses, and other stuff.   "Do me a favor" is not what Stackoverflow is here for. To answer questions (for you, and for posterity) is the purpose of the site. Conversational and multi-question posts like this belong on a Delphi forum of some kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run a console app and hide the console window, call `CreateProcess` passing `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` in the creation flags parameter.

Comment: How do you prefer to or need to communicate with console app? Passing arguments or stdin?

Comment: like normal user writing, but programmatically.

Comment: When I have done this before, I used `hStdInput` in [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686331(v=VS.85).aspx). You create a file with `CreateFile` and then write to it with `WriteFile`. Remember to set the file pointer back to the beginning of the file. Or you can use a pipe.

Comment: I don't know anything much about pipes.